# Set tintColor in macCatalyst

Tags: swift, uikit, mac-catalyst, tintcolor, macos-big-sur

In macOS Big Sur a `multicolor` accent color is allowed, no longer overwriting an app’s custom tint color (in theory).

[image: preferences]

This can be seen in a few system apps:

[image: podcasts]
[image: music]

(images from [this tweet](https://twitter.com/_dte/status/1275494371249532929))

However setting the `tintColor` property of a view, a window, or even `UIView.appearance()` still results in the default blue in macCatalyst. Not even setting `onTintColor` of a checkbox (`UISwitch`) has any effect.

[image: error]

Is this a bug or is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it the same way you set tint color for a Watch app:

1. Open the app’s asset catalog.
2. Select the Editor > Add New Asset > Color Set menu item to add a new color set to the asset catalog.
3. In the app’s Build Settings, set the “Global Accent Color Name” to your color set’s name.

Apple’s WatchKit instructions are here, but it’s actually the same for all platforms: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/setting_the_app_s_tint_color

Comment: link is broken now